# Help with typesetting Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to produce a beamer presentation with slides handout format as a pdf file.  Below is a portion of the code, including everything I have in the preface and a sample snippet of the body of my presentation:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[belowskip=-1pt,aboveskip=0pt,labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mode<presentation>


\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}


\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %get rid of the navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}

\title[Title 1]{Title}
\author{Author name}
\date{ \vskip 0.45em August 1, 2022}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\note{1, Notes}
\end{frame}

\section[Outline]{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]
\note{\footnotesize Notes 2}
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
   \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{Outline}
       \tableofcontents[currentsection]
   \end{frame}
}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\begin{frame}{Title 2}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow]{Definition}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Sub item 1 
        \end{itemize}
    \item Item 2 \pause
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Sub item 1 
            \item Sub item 2
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\note{1, Notes 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}{Conclusion}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow]{Title 2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1 \pause
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Sub item 1 
            %\item Sub item 2 
            \item Sub item 3 
            %\item Sub item 4 
        \end{enumerate}
    %\item  Item 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\note{\small 1, Notes 3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm getting a TON of errors when I typeset :-(  I've run this file successfully in the past on an old laptop, so I'm not sure if the problem is how it's installed on my new laptop.  I need to have the presentation completed by the end of the week, so any quick input would be appreciated.  For confidentiality purposes, I cannot include the entire presentation code.  However, if you're willing to communicate further via email, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a complete minimal working example which allows us to reproduce the errors and show your .log file? The preamble includes some unnecessary package, but by itself does not yet produce errors. We really need to see your code and how you compile your document if we should try to help you.

Comment: For a quick workaround to keep your deadline, you could have a look at online compilers like www.overleaf.com (if you don't have any confidential stuff in your presentation)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've edited the content of my question, hopefully my edits help to clarify.  Unfortunately, I cannot add the full code on here because of the content and graphics file included in my presentation.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The code works fine for me. Can you show your log file so we can what kind of errors you get?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The log file that comes when I run the above code is really long (42 pages in Word), and is showing 101 errors and 13 warnings.  Is there a way I can send the log file to you privately?

Comment: If it is too long for the question, you could share it via services like https://pastebin.com/ or put it on github

Comment: You don't need to post all 101 errors, the first one is usually the real culprit, everything coming after that is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: @campa Thanks a lot for the tip, this is the first error message I see: ! Package ifvtex Error: Name clash, \ifvtex is already defined.

See the ifvtex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.170     }
           %
Incompatible versions of \ifvtex can cause problems,
therefore package loading is aborted.

Comment: @user3911873 Please do post the complete log file. The problem might be some outdated package in a local folder or something. Impossible to diagnose with just the error message and having the complete log file makes it much easier to find such things by making a diff to a working log file.